# Servlet 3.0 and resources

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

If I create following the Servlet 3.0 specification a web application fragment how can I attach resource files, like css or images, to the fragment jsr?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You need to create the resources folder under your META-INF fonder, and put files there.

Maybe this [article](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/blogs/2010/08/13/pluggability-in-servlet-spec-3-0/) can help you.